# Axios request returns error 500 (laravel, axios & vuejs)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

My axios request (combined with Laravel) gives me a 500 error in the web console when I try to save a new question (= Frage):

```
"Error: Request failed with status code 500"
```

**VueJS-method save():**

```
save: function(){
    axios.post('/api/save-frage', this.Frage) //passes the object this.Frage
        .then(res => {
            // nothing here
            });
}
```

**api.php:**

```
Route::post('/save-frage','FragenController@store');
```

**FragenController.php (Controller):**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // validation coming soon :)
        $frage = new Frage;
        $frage->Frage = request('Fragentext');
        $frage->save(); //if I comment this out, there's no error 500 :)
    }
```

**Frage.php (Model):**

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class Frage extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'fragen';
        protected $fillable = ['Frage']; // only field to fill is called "Frage"

    }
```

I thought maybe the route was wrong (api.php), but if I change this, I then get a 404 error, so I guess this is correct, since otherwise there would have always been a 404 error.
Then I checked the model if maybe the table or fields were protected but this looks good to me.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So, can you show, what you have in $request? `dd($request->all())`

Comment: `status code 500`  is a generic "catch-all" response. Check the `/storage/logs/laravel.log` file to see the error trace

Comment: Did you check web inspector, XHR tab?

Comment: Use Insomnia to debug it. It will point you out the error.

Comment: could you add your error from the response? you can find it in the network tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, by looking in the XHR tab, as well as in laravel.log I saw the issue:

I reused an older table ("Frage") that

1. didn't have the necessary "created_at" and "updated_at" columns.
2. has lots of other columns beside "Frage" without a default value, that needed input as well.

**My solution:**

1. add the missing two columns
2. send the other column values in the this.Frage also.